# Cancel uninstallation when custom action fail wix

Tags: wix, custom-action

I need to Cancel uninstallation when my custom action is failed. However i am unable to cancel uninstallation, may i know what is my mistake?

```
<CustomAction Id="SetRemoveSettings" FileKey="RemoveSettings.exe"  ExeCommand="" Execute="deferred" Return="check" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="yes" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='SetRemoveSettings' Before='InstallFinalize'>REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should rollback the uninstall if your EXE returns a non zero exit code.

Also, you should look into the [Quiet Exec Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) pattern.  It's a better way of calling EXE's for those times that you must call an EXE.  Otherwise avoid EXE's in general.